# Python stream data into an opened excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying stream data from Python to an **opened** excel file. I've been using `openpyxl` to do this. Here's the code that I've so far,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('some_data.xlsx')
ws = wb['MySheet']

while True:
    current_val = some_method_that_gives_data()
    ws['A1'].value = current_val
    wb.save('some_data.xlsx')
```

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is to be able to update the excel data in realtime from Python. The problem is updating data this way gives permission error if the file is already open in MS-Excel (but I want to be able to update it while being open in other apps).

I guess this has more to do with file handling at the OS level, but I'm not able to figure out the solution for this issue.